# Clarification on RefSeq Genes track on IGV

Tags: exons, introns

The following picture is a snapshot of the **RefSeq Genes** track (collapsed) on [IGV](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/). I know that the bold blue line indicates exons and the thin one indicates introns.

However, I cannot find what the medium line stands for. Is it part of the exon? Why is it different?

I have checked into the manual but I couldn't find any relevant info.

[image]

When you expand the track (bottom picture) even more diverse lines appear.

1. medium blue line without arrows
2. medium line with arrows
3. bold line with arrows

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between all of them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thinnest blue line is intron, so not in your transcript.  The medium thickness segment is untranslated exon, the thickest blue segment is translated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. Do you have any insight on the meaning of the arrows? Why some medium blue lines have it and some not?